# Check when scrolled to the right

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset, horizontal-scrolling

I want to be able to detect if a user has scrolled through an entire div with `overlfow:scroll;`
the div is horizontal though, so using `offset().top` doesn't work here.
I currently have this code:

```
var elem = $('#slide');
var inner = $('#slidecontain');
if ( Math.abs(inner.offset().top) + elem.height() + elem.offset().top >= inner.outerHeight() ) {
  alert('bottom')
}
```

this works perfectly for checking when I've scrolled to the bottom, but since its a horizontal scroll it fires immediately.  How can I switch this? Is `offset().left` a possibility?

Here's the html, pretty basic:

```
<div id="slide" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">
        <div id="slidecontain" style="width: 900px; height: 150px;">
            <div class="slide1" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></div>
            <div class="slide2" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></div>
            <div class="slide3" style="width: 300px; height: 150px;"></div>
        </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html (with the CSS) too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be easly done with jQuery using [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

```
var elem = $('#slide');
var inner = $('#slidecontain');

elem.scroll(function() {
   if(elem.scrollLeft() + elem.width() == inner.width()) {
       alert("reached end!");
   }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hz9j/) simulating this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [**.scrollLeft()**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) in jQuery which can be used here.  But in a reverse fashion.

Which looking for some working example I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9ehs/2/), given by @Merianos Nikos

How it works?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="inner">
    <div id="long"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var lastLeftLocation = 0;
    $('.inner').scroll(

    function (e) {
        if (lastLeftLocation > $(this).scrollLeft()) {

        } else {
            console.log("moved to right");
        }
        lastLeftLocation = e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
    });
});
```

here is the simplified version of [**jsfiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/T9ehs/4/)

**FYI:** There is no reverse method **`.scrollRight()`** ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a React based solution, you can try this out:

```
const containerRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const isScrolledRight = () => {
  if (containerRef.current) {
    const { current } = containerRef;
    return Math.abs(current.scrollWidth - current.clientWidth - current.scrollLeft) <= 1;
  }
  return false;
};

return(
  <div className='cardContainer' ref={containerRef}>
    <div className='card'><p>card text</p></div>
    <div className='card'><p>card text</p></div>
    <div className='card'><p>card text</p></div>
    <div className='card'><p>card text</p></div>
  </div>
)
```

CSS:

```css
.cardContainer {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 160px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.card {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

> `Element.scrollLeft` is a non-rounded number, while
> `Element.scrollWidth` and `Element.clientWidth` are rounded - so the
> only way to determine if the scroll area is scrolled to the bottom is
> by seeing if the scroll amount is close enough to some threshold (i.e.
> 1 in this case).

Reference: [Scroll height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)